# deprecated react-native-listview error in form builder react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

If I am using this in my **code** ..

```
"import GenerateForm from 'react-native-form-builder"
"react-native-form-builder": "^1.0.16", (in package.json)
```

I am getting **error** that:

> deprecated react-native-listview

While I am not using any listview in my code .

**`package-lock-json`**

```
"react-native-form-builder": {
      "version": "1.0.16",
      "resolved": "https://nexus.tecnotree.com/repository/npm-public/react-native-form-builder/-/react-native-form-builder-1.0.16.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-KGYuxHHVCG7O5yyVSp8hdDkDe6kthEKCwALJDGGoDmzXd7f9nBHde3zWnA5hdg9CmugSzk3o7r35don66zeTgw==",
      "requires": {
        "fs-extra": "^3.0.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "print-message": "^2.1.0",
        "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
        "react-native-i18n": "^1.0.0",
        "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.5.0"
      },
```

Comment: **react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view** is using ListView.

Comment: then how can i fix it?

Comment: use latest version of **react-native-form-builder** which uses latest version of **react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view**.